# Flutter adding ChangeNotifierProvider by list

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to add a list of ChangeNotifierProviders. I receive no errors but looking at the Inspector is just shows ChangeNotifierProvider<ChangeNotifier> instead of the name of the ChangeNotifierProvider<nameofprovider> provided in the list. List<ChangeNotifier> changeNotifiers = [nameofprovider()]; The Net is constant and shows correctly with ChangeNotifierProvider<Net>.

```
      home: MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Net()),
            for (ChangeNotifier changeNotifier in changeNotifiers)
              ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => changeNotifier),
          ],
          child: const MainPage(),
        ),
```